# JUnit 4.12 - get test name in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, junit4

I have been trying to get the test method name using the testname rule in Scala 2.11, using JUnit 4.12, but it just prints 'null' for the test name. Below is how I tried to implement it but does not work. Am I missing something here? Is there any other way I can get the test method name?

```
  import org.junit.rules.TestName

  var _testName = new TestName

  @Rule
  def testName: TestName = _testName

  def afterEach() {
   print(testName.getMethodName)
   }
```